# High-impedance in RTL

Tags: synthesis, digital-logic

What is the purpose of the code in the "else" line:

```
if RdEnabB = '1' then
  DoutB <= regfile(to_integer(unsigned(RdAddrB)));
else
  DoutB <= (others => 'Z');
end if;
```

in the accepted answer of this post:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100620/vhdl-how-to-double-read-a-register-bank/100756#100756

Questions:
 1. Why are the DoutX values driven to high-impedance when they are not read?
 2. Does this have an effect on synthesis?
 3. Is this for simulation purposes only?

Answer (score 2):

1. We can only guess the reason. Power saving could be one of the possibilities.
2. Yes. If the technology supports high-impedance, the circuit will be synthesized appropriately.
3. No. Answer 2 tells why.

Comment: About 2, I've read that modern FPGA chips support tristate only on I/O pins, and not in the internal fabric. What would the above code infer if used internally... multiplexers?

Is this valid coding for an FPGA and for an internal bus?

Comment: @evilpascal You're right. Most of the FPGAs only support tristate on I/Os. Also not on all I/Os, but only on the ones that have the appropriate resistors (e.g. pull-up/pull-down). If the synthesis tool cannot map the 'Z' assignment, it's expected to give an error. In addition, I don't know if any FPGA family's RAMs have tristate support as in your example.